# Linq to SQL delete a record from database taken from another context

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, delete-row

The following code:

```
var record = GetDatabaseRecordByID(UniqueObjectID);

if (record != null)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        db.GetTable(typeof(T2)).DeleteOnSubmit(record);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Throws this error:

> Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.

This error returns, because `GetDatabaseRecordByID()` retrieves the record from a different `DBContext`.

The code has turned out this way over time due to some difficult refactoring required from some equally difficult caching bugs.  I can create a new override method for `GetDatabaseRecordByID(DBContext... )` but would prefer to avoid this if possible.

Is it at all possible to delete a record from a different context? I am assuming the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing a fairly big refactor, I think the answer to this question is no it's not possible.